# Remove empty string from a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe that contains a list of names with such a structure:

```
df['name']=[

['anna','karen','',]
['', 'peter','mark','john']

]
```

I want to get rid of the empty strings i tried it with list comprehension

```
[[name for name in df['name'] if name.strip()] for df['name'] in df]
```

But that doesnt work at all, is there a way to do it? I also used the replace method from pandas
by replacing the empty strings to nan but that also doesnt work as it always throws a key error...

```
df['name'].replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: First things first, why do you have lists in a column?

Comment: the data above is dummy data, the data i have has to be stored in lists so i can do analysis on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension isn't quite right, `for df['name'] in df` doesn't make sense. Try with:

```
df['name'] = [[s for s in l if s] for l in df['name']]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':[['anna','karen','',], ['', 'peter','mark','john']]})

df['name'] = [[s for s in l if s] for l in df['name']]
print(df)
                 name
0        [anna, karen]
1  [peter, mark, john]
```

Comment: feel kinda dumb, thanks anyway! Btw do you know why the replace method from pandas throws keyerrors?

Comment: Because its ment for strings, not lists @voltage

Comment: I know thats why i unstacked them to series elements weird

Comment: Try with a column of strings and yo'll see @volt

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the filter function

```
df['name'] = [list(filter(None, sublist)) for sublist in df['name']]
```

Comment: `filter(None, sublist)` is shorter.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of that :)